# AVPlayerViewController next/prev buttons don't work?

Tags: ios, button, avplayer, avqueueplayer

My code:

```
AVQueuePlayer *player = ...;
AVPlayerViewController *controller = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
    [vc presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
    controller.player = player;
    controller.allowsPictureInPicturePlayback = NO;
    [player play];
```

`AVQueuePlayer` is like `AVPlayer` but supports multiple items.

The problem is `AVPlayerViewController` has "go next/prev" buttons and they don't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all media is capable of fast forwarding / skipping or rewinding.
The `AVPlayer` does not allow you to override that functionality.

In order to check if the media is capable of fast forward or rewind, see the values of `canPlayFastForward` and `canPlayFastReverse` in `AVPlayerItem`.

If you really want to override the Next/Prev buttons, I think your only shot is to make a custom `AVPlayerViewController`.

Comment: I don't need `canPlayFastForward` and `canPlayFastReverse` - I need `canStepFastForward` and `canStepFastReverse`. Anyways item supports slow and fast forward and `canStepFastForward == YES` but the buttons still don't work

Comment: Right, isn't "stepping" done by holding the buttons? Or maybe dragging and dropping the video timeline is ment by stepping. I'm not sure.

Comment: Holding buttons means scroll forward/backward. I mean it should go to next/prev video with a single button click